# Why is my navigation bar margin overlapping my main content margin?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering why the navbar margin (specifically: margin-bottom 50px) overlaps with the main-content margin (specifically: margin-top 50px).

```
HTML

    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="../Assets/Logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="navbar-logo">
        <ul class="navbar-link">
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link-item">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link-item">Affliates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link-item">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link-item">Communities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link-item join-button">Join Waitlist</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main class="main-content">
        <section class="text-section">
            <span>We are now allowing early-access for users. <a href="#">Learn more.</a></span>
            <h1>Build a highly engaged community with no effort.</h1>
            <p>Commune offers the tools you need to build a highly engaged community with little to no effort. Simply
                setup
                your Commune workspace, and manage everything from members to content from one central dashboard.</p>
            <div>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address">
                <a href="#">Join Waitlist</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="illustration">
            <img src="../Assets/Illustration.png" alt="Illustration" class="illustration-img">
        </section>
    </main>
```

```
CSS

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 50px 0;
}

.navbar-link li, .navbar-link {
    display: inline;

.main-content {
    display: flex;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Have attached some pictures for easy reference!

- Navigation bar margin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKtsc.png
- Main content margin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iURsF.png

Thank you for reading, and appreciate the help! :)

Comment: You are missing `}` closing bracket in CSS file for `navbar-link` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

It's the concept of margin collapsing ...

Go through this
[Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)